# Is there a way to put a user input text in the top right corner of a chart?

Tags: text, label, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to put some text in the top right or top left of a chart depending on a user selection. I have the following code but this puts the text right above the current price (which is a little too close). I'd like it to appear further away, like in the very top right of the chart or the very top left. Is this possible?

I have the following code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Setting Up", overlay = true)
import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4

Trade_Update = input.string(" ","Trade Update",options=[" ","Long Setting Up", "Short Setting Up", "Long Underway", "Short Underway"])
var label l = na
if (barstate.islast)
    l := label.new(bar_index,VisibleChart.high() ,text=Trade_Update,yloc = yloc.abovebar,textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_none)
    label.delete(l[1])[MES PineScript label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyyh.png)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Setting Up", overlay = true)
import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4

Trade_Update = input.string(" ","Trade Update",options=[" ","Long Setting Up", "Short Setting Up", "Long Underway", "Short Underway"])
var label l = na
// if (barstate.islast)
// l := label.new(bar_index,VisibleChart.high() ,text=Trade_Update,yloc = yloc.abovebar,textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_none)
// label.delete(l[1])
// [MES PineScript label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyyh.png)
var table tradeTable = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1, border_width=1)
table.cell(tradeTable, 0, 0, Trade_Update, bgcolor=color.navy, text_color=color.white)
```

Comment: Thank you @SRPV. I just discovered tables, it's a way better way to display information :)